# Vb.Net DataRelation 'column' argument cannot be null. Parameter name column

Tags: vb.net, null, addition, datarelation

I have a query that display results as follows: 
[image]

Now I want to display these results in a tree view in vb.net using datarelation. I will add the groupId as the parent and the other details as children in the tree view. I could have done this by using a loop, but I am interested in doing this via datarelation property of datatables. So first I will create a new table with distinct groupId as follows:

```
Dim tbl As DataTable = dsDataset.Tables("groups").DefaultView.ToTable(True, "groupId")
```

Then add this table to the dataset to able to add datarelation.

```
tbl.TableName = "aaa"
dsDataset.Tables.Add("aaa")
```

And finally add a datarelation between the new table and the original table:

```
 Dim rel As New DataRelation("model", dsDataset.Tables("aaa").Columns("groupId"), dsDataset.Tables("groups").Columns("groupId"))
```

After running this code and when I get to part of creating this relation the following error occures:

```
'column' argument cannot be null.
Parameter name column
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is here...

```
 tbl.TableName = "aaa"
 dsDataset.Tables.Add("aaa") 'Your not adding the table...
```

Try this instead...

```
 dsDataset.Tables.Add(tbl)
```

Comment: This would not solve the problem because I have dont have the problem in adding the table in the dataset. The problem in creating the relation between the two tables